# java.lang.NullPointerException: name is null when proguard enable

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-proguard

I am getting `java.lang.NullPointerException: name is null` when i am enabling proguard in debug mode, my app is working fine in debug mmode when i am using without proguard . here is the snippet i am using to enable proguard

```
debug{
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```

here is error log which i am getting

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: name is null
        at android.content.res.Resources.getIdentifier(Resources.java:3708)
        at com.byteapp.postearnmoney.b.a.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.byteapp.postearnmoney.b.a.a(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$a.a(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$a.b(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$p.a(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$p.a(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$p.a(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$p.c(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$c.a(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.a(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.a(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.c(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.N(Unknown Source)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(Unknown Source)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)
        at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(Unknown Source)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:716)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:462)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(Unknown Source)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6333)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:3140)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20236)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2704)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1656)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1948)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1544)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7607)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRe
05-08 18:12:58.646 24073-24535/com.byteapp.postearnmoney E/File: fail readDirectory() errno=2
    fail readDirectory() errno=2
05-08 18:13:04.586 24073-24453/com.byteapp.postearnmoney E/Ads: Fail to get isAdIdFakeForDebugLogging
    java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for the service connection
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.a.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):202)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.a.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):20)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.a.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):148)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.d.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):6)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.b.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):4)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.m.call(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):3)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.n.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):3)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for the service connection
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.a.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):189)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.a.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):20) 
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.a.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):148) 
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.d.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):6) 
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.b.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):4) 
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.m.call(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):3) 
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.n.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):3) 
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
05-08 18:13:04.996 24073-24484/com.byteapp.postearnmoney E/Ads: Fail to get isAdIdFakeForDebugLogging
    java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for the service connection
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.a.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):202)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.a.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):20)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.a.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):148)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.d.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):6)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.b.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):4)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.m.call(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):3)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.n.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):3)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for the service connection
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.a.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):189)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.a.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):20) 
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.a.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):148) 
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.d.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):6) 
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.b.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):4) 
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.m.call(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):3) 
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.n.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):3) 
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
05-08 18:13:05.276 24073-24495/com.byteapp.postearnmoney E/Ads: Fail to get isAdIdFakeForDebugLogging
    java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for the service connection
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.a.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):202)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.a.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):20)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.a.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):148)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.d.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):6)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.b.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):4)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.m.call(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):3)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.n.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):3)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for the service connection
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.a.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):189)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.a.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):20) 
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.a.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):148) 
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.d.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):6) 
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.b.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):4) 
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.m.call(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):3) 
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.n.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesa@12529019@12.5.29 (040306-192802242):3) 
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: feel free to click on first `Unknown Source` in `at com.byteapp.postearnmoney.b.a.a(Unknown Source)` to check where the exception appear and provide some code

Comment: post your app module build.gradle please

Comment: by the way if you look closely there is the reason for this exception. In your log it clearly says that this exception is caused due to service time out. and you got null as a result.

Comment: @Selvin `Unknown Source` is not Clickable

Comment: you have code like `String name = null;` and then `Resources.getIdentifier(name, ....)` and that's why you are getting NPE ...

Comment: Thank you @Selvin , i was doing that same mistake which you mentioned, I solved it by adding `@Keep` annotation on model class.

Answer (score -1):

you may need to add this `shrinkResources true`
[shink-code](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code)

> Resource shrinking works only in conjunction with code shrinking. After the code shrinker removes all unused code, the resource shrinker can identify which resources the app still uses. This is especially true when you add code libraries that include resources—you must remove unused library code so the library resources become unreferenced and, thus, removable by the resource shrinker.

Comment: how this would help?

Comment: again *how this would help?* it will cut unused resources ... how this would fix his NPE ?

Comment: try to read it carefully please @Selvin "the resource shrinker can identify which resources the app still uses", because Proguard may remove the resources what make NPE

Comment: try to read it with understanding ... not using it (like he does) it will not remove unused resources ... using this option(shrinkResources true) will remove unused resources ... HOW THIS WOULD HELP ... **ProGuard shrinks CODE ONLY**

Comment: he has some code like `String name = null;` and then `Resources.getIdentifier(name, ....)` and that's why he is getting NPE ... shrinking resource has nothing to do with that